# Rademacher complexity of linear function class with compact parameter space and support

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the class of functions $\mathcal{F}$ of the form $f_\theta(x) = \langle x,\theta \rangle$ where $\theta \in \{\theta \in R^d : ||\theta||_1 \leq r\}$ and x has support $\{x \in R^d : ||x||_\infty \leq M\}$.

Give an upper bound for the Rademacher complexity:

$$R_n(\mathcal{F}) = \frac{1}{n} E \sup_{||\theta||_1 \leq r} \left|\sum_i^n \epsilon_i \langle x_i, \theta \rangle\right|$$

where $epsilon_i$ are symmetric iid bernoullis on {-1,1}.

My approach:

Since the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ norms are dual norms we have the bound on the inner product $\langle x_i, \theta \rangle \leq ||x||_\infty||\theta||_1 \leq Mr$

And by Jensen's inequality:

$$E\left| \sum_i^n \epsilon_i  \right| \leq \sqrt{E\left( \sum_i^n \epsilon_i  \right)^2} = \sqrt{n}$$

Where the equality follows by independence.

So we have the final upper bound: $Mr/\sqrt{n}$ which is better than the solution found here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/stats300b/Exercises/Solutions/ex6-sol.pdf (problem 7.3b) which contains an additional $\sqrt{\log 2d}$ factor (by an argument around subgaussianity).

I could use some feedback on my derivation.

Comment: From $|\langle x_i, \theta\rangle| \leq C$, you cannot deduce that $|\sum_i \epsilon_i \langle x_i, \theta\rangle| \leq C |\sum_i \epsilon_i|$, but only that $|\sum_i \epsilon_i \langle x_i, \theta\rangle| \leq C \sum_i |\epsilon_i|$, at which point you have lost too much. This makes your argument invalid (I think).

Comment: oh that's right :) That's why in the solution linked they absorb the summation into the norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question above: $|\sum_i \epsilon_i \langle x_i, \theta\rangle| \leq ||\theta||_1 ||x||_\infty |\sum_i \epsilon_i|$ is not valid since $\epsilon_i$ and $\langle x_i, \theta\rangle$ could be negative for some $i$.